# How to check the following things while using WATIR 1] Internet Connection failure while processing 2] website page is not accessible

Tags: watir

How to check the following things while using WATIR
1]    Internet Connection failure while processing
2]     website page is not accessible

Comment: How would you manually check for those problems?

Comment: If a site is unavailable or times out, then the watir script(s) will throw an error.

Comment: yes, you are right.i will try something else

Comment: @orde how can i check time out or unavailable ?

Comment: oecprashant: the 'open-uri' answer from @Rakesh will tell you if a site is unavailable.  @Chuck's suggestion of using `HTTParty` is sound as well.  In terms of testing timeouts--IMHO--that's a bit unusual because it's a non-deterministic scenario (i.e. you don't know when the existing connection would fail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'open-uri'

def internet_connection_check
  begin
    true if open("http://www.facebook.com/")
  rescue
    false
  end
end
```

Try it will work

Answer (score 0):

Watir drives the web browser, the browser itself has really no way of knowing if the system has a proper network connection, or even if it does, if that network connects to the internet.  OTOH it does tend to know if it can't find a requested web page

About the best you can do is use a browser like chrome that tends to have responses where you can look for specific text in the dom that indicated the browser could not find the site.  If that happens when trying to connect to a well known high availability site like google.com it's a good bet you don't have a valid network connection

Another option might be to use a library like HTTPARTY or REST-Client which will let you construct an http request and then inspect the result to see what the result code is.